# Access subscript of array of type any refering to dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, types, any

There are a lot of questions on SO about using a subscript on an Array of objects of type ANY that generally recommend casting the Any Object to a variable type that can take a subscript with something like

```
if let addresses = profile["Addresses"] as? [[String: Any]]
```

In my case, the Array is an array of dictionaries of form (paramName:value) or (NSString: Float), however, despite all the answers on SO, I can't figure out the syntax to tell the compiler that the Any object is a dictionary.

My original code generates the error:

```
func getStringFromSortedArray (sortedArray:Array<Any>) -> String{

for i in 0 ..< sortedArray.count {
  if let paramName = sortedArray[i]["param"]  {
               //run some code
}
```

I have tried

```
for i in 0 ..< sortedArray.count {
  if let paramName = sortedArray[i]["param"] as? [[String: Any]]  {
               //run some code
}
```

,

```
if let sortedArray = sortedArray as? [[Dictionary: Any]] {                
for i in 0 ..< sortedArray.count {
  if let paramName = sortedArray[i]["param"]  {
               //run some code
}
}
```

and a whole lot of variations without success.

Can someone point me to correct syntax to inform compiler that the Any object is a dictionary?  If someone thinks this question has been answered before, I would appreciate your point me to an example with an array of dictionaries as I have already looked at answers with different setups.

Comment: You've gone down a very tricky path. Rather than trying to work this out, you want to get rid of the `Any` types. If you have `[String: Any]` that almost certainly can be converted to a struct, and then `[Any]` will become an array of that struct, and all these problems will go away. `Any` sometimes shows up when data comes into the system, but you should immediately convert it to a real type. If you're passing around values of type `[Any]`, you're on the wrong road. What's your initial data look like?

Comment: Anyway the "proper" syntax would be `if let sortedArray = sortedArray as? [[String: Any]] {`.

Comment: The sorted array of dictionaries has a lot of values for parameters such as param1:.42, param2:.28,param3:.22 sorted by the value.

Comment: @luk2302, that allowed it to compile but I don't understand what is gong on. What does it mean to downcast an array to strings or is it a string and an any referring to the float?

Comment: @user1904273 `[String:Any]` is simply how you say "Dictionary". (Technically it would be `[AnyHashable:Any`] but in real life keys are usually String so it's just as well to say so.) So "Array of Dictionaries" is `[[String:Any]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just look at the problem with your first line of code:

```
  func getStringFromSortedArray (sortedArray:Array<Any>) -> String {
```

This is wrong because you are not saying what the type of the array elements is. You *know* it is an array of dictionaries, but you are hiding that fact from the compiler. This means you can't go anywhere from here.

So if you know it is an array of dictionaries, you should *say* it is an array of dictionaries:

```
  func getStringFromSortedArray (sortedArray:[[AnyHashable:Any]]) -> String {
```

Now, if you know more, you should say more. For example, if you know that all the *keys* in these dictionaries are strings, you should say so:

```
  func getStringFromSortedArray (sortedArray:[[String:Any]]) -> String {
```

If you know that the *values* in the dictionaries are all of the same type, you should say that too:

```
  func getStringFromSortedArray (sortedArray:[[String:Float]]) -> String {
```

Always be as specific as you can when you declare the type of something.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are saying that `sortedArray` is an array of dictionaries like `[[String : Any]]`.  I *believe* you are also saying that the key "param" contains a String, and that is what you're trying to get out of this function.  If that is correct then it seems you were very close, but missing a few things:

```
func getStringFromSortedArray (sortedArray:Array<Any>) -> String {
  //If your sortedArray is an array of dictionaries let's cast it as such
  guard let dictionaries = sortedArray as? [[String : Any]] else { return "None Found" }
  for i in 0 ..< dictionaries.count {
    //Now we can loop through the dictionaries, and check that "param" contains a string
    if let paramName = dictionaries[i]["param"] as? String {
      //Now we have a reference to "paramName" and can return it or do whatever "run some code" means
           //run some code
  }
}
```

Of course you will need to customize what happens if the `guard` statement fails, and you'll also have to add a valid return value if your for loop completes without finding the value you are looking for.